# Is it possible to directly embed a Shiny app in a bookdown document?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, bookdown, gitbook

By "directly" I mean not by uploading the app and then using `knitr::include_app`, but rather entering the source code of the app itself into the Bookdown document.

Rmarkdown supports this, but neither [this](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/interactive-documents.html#intro-shiny) approach, nor [this](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/shiny-embedded.html#shiny-embed-inline) seems to work with Bookdown. (The former gives an "Error: path for html_dependency not provided" error, the latter displays an empty frame.)

Comment: No, it is not possible. Sorry.

Comment: @YihuiXie I'm sorry to hear this, but thanks for the information! Are there any plans to change this situation...? (PS. I happily accept your answer, if you'd convert it to an actual answer.)

Comment: Actually if the "book" only has one HTML output file (typically it has multiple output files, each being a "chapter"), you may be able to use Shiny. It depends on what you use **bookdown** for.

Comment: @YihuiXie Yes, unfortunately I have a "usual" (multi-chaptered) Bookdown file...